# NodeJS: Manage processes

Tags: node.js, node-webkit

I want to be able to kill processes (widows\linux) like "chrome.exe" and others from NodeJS. I walked through a lot of information and i couldn't find any usefull information, instead of node child processes. I'm using NodeJS with NW to build desktop application.

Is it possible?

Comment: Share what you had tried so far and where you are facing problem.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you could use [ps-node](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ps-node) to do this.

Something like:

```
var ps = require('ps-node');

    ps.lookup({
        command: 'chrome',
    }, function(err, resultList ) {
         if (err) {
              throw new Error( err );
         }

         resultList.forEach(function( process ){
              if( process ){

                    ps.kill( process.pid, function( err ) {
                        if (err) {
                             throw new Error( err );
                        }
                        else {
                             console.log( 'Process %s has been killed!', pid );
                        }
                    });
              }
         });
    });
```